# User management of periodic tasks in django celery app

Tags: django, celery, scheduling, celerybeat, djcelery

Django celery (djcelery) is considered obselete these days, but to me it seems to offer some unique features still. For example with djcelery one can allow the user to add a periodic task easily by creating an instance of their `PeriodicTask`. Is this the best way to do this? If not how else could I allow users to manage periodic tasks in a django+celery app?
(Just to be clear I know I can hardcode periodic tasks in `settings.py` celery beat schedule with `djcelery`, but I'm talking about user management of periodic tasks, creating/updating/listing/deleting, via the admin or some mini app which interfaces a model like djcelery's `PeriodicTask` model)

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but like I said in the OP,I believe there are some things, which I've discussed, that are still not possible out of the box without djcelery.